# How to pass value of radio button to another form field using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I want to pass the value either `no` or `1` to the input `name="auth[]"` below.

```
<td> send
    <input type="radio" name="authorized[]'.$c.'" id="send'.$c.'"value="1" checked> 
</td> 
<td> no
    <input label="no" type="radio" name="authorized[]'.$c.'" id="no'.$c.'"value="no" >
    <input name="auth[]" type="hidden" class="mailclass" id="auth'.$c.'" value="" />
</td>
```

This code will pass the `no` value, but if someone were to reverse that decision and re-select send, it does not switch the value back to `1`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x='1'
    $( "input:radio" ).each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            x=$(this).val();
            alert(x);
            $(this).next('.mailclass').val(x);
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your selector. The `$(this).next...` isn't working. Using `click` is more better for your coding than `each`
I did this:

```
var x='1';
$( "input:radio" ).click(function() {        
        x=$(this).val();
        $('input.mailclass').val(x);
    })
});
```

And, here's a working **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richbuff/rdr204L3/)**.

Hope this helps! (Disclaimer: I can only see a small part of your code, but the root cause is your selector. Feel free to use a better selector if mine isn't optimal.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. My mistake for not being more clear. I only want the input name="auth[]" that immediately follows the radio button  to be changed. Your suggestion takes the last click and changes the value of "auth" for the whole array of inputs

Comment: Do you have more than 1 `name="auth[]"` in your HTML? There is only one in your example above. If you could show me the "full" html, then we can make this work. :-)

Comment: my script creates an array of form values for a large number of inputs. every radio button then is supposed to set the value of the name="auth[]" input directly below. This lets my sql query know whether or not to insert into the table for printing.